# For loop creating multiple dataframes which I need to get all common stats from (descibe function)

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I need to loop through around 500 dataframes with same rows and columns (simulation),
and then get the mean, mode,etc for each cell across the 500 dataframes.

So in the example below
We have 5 iterations,
so first value of column A, would have 5 different values
as would second value of column A etc from which I would need to calculate the mean, mode etc for that cell.

Ideally I would like to use the describe function.

I don't know how I should go about doing this.

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np




num_iterations = 5

for i in range(num_iterations):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3, 3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: I think it should work, however answers are old so not sure if the top answers are still the best way to handle the problem. Thank you.